# Can I get the current git commit in the ROS buildfarm binary packaging step?

Tags: ros, ros2, build, buildfarm

In our ros package providing a GUI tool we recently added the feature of showing the git commit hash of this build in the "about" window, to easily identify the running version.

After releasing, the CI fails (https://build.ros2.org/job/Rbin_uJ64__rig_reconfigure__ubuntu_jammy_amd64__binary/35/) with `fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /tmp)` when attempting to read the current git commit during building.

Is there a way of keeping access to the git directory in the packaging step? It seems to work in the PR build (https://build.ros2.org/job/Rpr__rig_reconfigure__ubuntu_jammy_amd64/1/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By the time your Debian binary is being built, the git history is long gone:

- When the PR build runs, it is simply checking out your repository, building your code, and running the tests. Therefore, you have git information available.
- When the binary Debian job is run, it doesn't actually use your repository - because it is actually building the Debian binary from the Debian source package.
- For your project, the Debian source job can be found [here](https://build.ros2.org/job/Rsrc_uJ__rig_reconfigure__ubuntu_jammy__source/). You'll also note this source job is an upstream dependency of the binary job you linked. This source job *might* have access to some of the git information, but the release is actually a git tag, not a branch. I'm not aware if there are any hooks that would allow you to do special steps during the source package build.

Comment: Released versions are built from tags. In that same spot the more typical thing to display would be the version tag. Then you're not tying the version info to the distribution mechanism.

Comment: I forgot about the tag vs branch aspect - that's still only for the source job though, right? Not git at all by the time the binary job is running?

Comment: Correct, bloom exports the tagged version from git and after that the version number is the unique identifier. It's in the release repo and can have maintenance patches applied. From that the source debs are created and from them the binaries. The build cannot rely on the code being in a git repository.